# How do I print a Python variable as an attribute value for XML file

Tags: python, xml

Python Version 3.6.8

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
```

Following is the code to generate XML file, XML file generation code is working fine. I need to write some values from variables. Variables are **i**, **height** and **width**.

```
frame = ET.SubElement(root, "frame", number="{i}")
objectlist = ET.SubElement(frame, "objectlist")
object = ET.SubElement(objectlist, "object", id="1")
ET.SubElement(object, "box", h="{height}", w="{width}")
```

How can I pass the variables in the given code? (First Line of Code and fourth line of code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please specify all the valuable information like *version of Python* and what is the library you are using (`ET`).

If this code is in Python 3.6 or later the most intuitive way would be to use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), which would be in your case:

```
frame = ET.SubElement(root, "frame", number=f"{i}"
```

(Note how the only change is `f` before the value of `number`)

You can do the same with any other string value.

Another way to achieve this would be to cast the value of `i` to string using `str(i)`, which will work the same but will lack the efficiency of f-strings.